# Equivalent condition for compact group to act transitively

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups

Let $ M $ be a connected manifold. Let $ \pi_1(M) $ be the fundamental group of $ M $.

Suppose there exists a compact group $ K $ that acts transitively on $ M $. Then $ \pi_1(M) $ must have a finite commutator subgroup. See [Transitive action by compact Lie group implies almost abelian fundamental group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321106/transitive-action-by-compact-lie-group-implies-almost-abelian-fundamental-group).

**On the other hand, suppose that a Lie group $ G $ acts transitively on a compact manifold $ M $. Furthermore suppose that $ \pi_1(M) $ has finite commutator subgroup. Then can we conclude that there exists some compact group $ K $ (probably related to the maximal compact subgroup of $ G $) which acts transitively on $ M $?**

If we strengthen our assumption from $ \pi_1(M) $ has a finite commutators subgroup to just the whole group $ \pi_1(M) $ is finite,  then the desired result is exactly Corollary 3 of Montgomery:
[Montgomery - Simply connected homogeneous spaces](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1950-0037311-6).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what finite-by-abelian means, but what about the transitive R-action (R=real numbers) on S^1 = R/Z?

Comment: @kiran Here a group is said to be finite-by-abelian if its derived subgroup is finite (i.e., extension with finite kernel and abelian quotient).